# Allowing others to copy and tweak my Rails app online

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications

I have developed a relatively simple Rails web application that others (non-programmers) may find useful. I would like to provide a web interface for anyone who wants to create their own copy of my app and change some minor settings, like the appearance, the name of the app and some of its resources, that type of thing. What kind of technology would allow me to do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Anniemo, to clarify, if you want this to work with non-programmers, it sounds like you'd have to make some changes on your app? If the answers below are not what you are looking for would yo please add more detail to your question to explain what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

[GitHub](https://github.com/) is probably one of the most popular tools to support this, but there are many others such as  [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/). I'd start from there and do some research to decide the best one for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to collaborate code online is through git.  The most popular sites for git management include [GitHub](https://github.com/) and [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/).  Here's a good article suggesting [nine alternatives](http://technologyadvice.com/blog/information-technology/github-alternatives/).

However, you stated it would be used by "non-programmers".  I can't tell if they will find it useful through the function of the application or the simplicity of the code, so it seems reasonable to also suggest non-git options.

You could use something like [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/) or [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/) to host the static files.  See the [AWS S3 docs](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/getting-started/) regarding creating a bucket and adding an object.

If you would like to host the entire application online and allow users to easily edit and view the application in-browser, check out [cloud9](https://c9.io/).

Comment: Good point about the non-programmers. I think the OP should clarify a little more what he is trying to do.